# Which programming language is easier to support

Tags: programming-languages

Which programming language is it easier to support developers in (namely developers that have little professional experience (i.e. dealing with changes out of their control)).

Edit: I would define support as

- not restrict the professional development of the developer and enable them to grow
- enable senior staff to work alongside them in a similar environment and not be frustrated

Context: I'm looking into developing new products in either ruby or python, and I'm looking for possible alternatives that works well in a team environment. That is, which beginner language works best in a full spectrum team?

Comment: You might want to be a little more specific about what you mean by support: train, maintain the development tools, be a manager, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=programming+language+beginners Almost every single one of these will contain an answer for you.

Comment: Comparative makes me expect alternatives to choose between ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write complex idiocy in every one of them.

Comment: There is a difference in tolerated idiocy levels though.

Answer (score 3):

Important thing is writing clean and consistent code.

On the other hand, what you wish to do is alsa important. Do you want to develop a web application or a desktop application. Will it be a simple code or complicated one.

There are simple languages like [alice](http://www.alice.org/) for teaching children programming and multifunctional ones like java, which you can develop desktop, web or mobile device applications

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with changes out of their control is never easy in any language. I cannot think of one  language easier for newbies. I can think of languages that are more complicated than others but really in the end they all have the potential for obscure badly written code impossible to maintain.

I guess you could say procedural code is less complex the oop. But not to an oop guy trust me.

Answer (score 1):

More important than the language itself, what skills does your team have?  If your team is going to support applications written in a particular language, I hope they have in-depth knowledge on it.

Using most modern languages can accomplish your requirements, with each having good and bad aspects.  Make sure the team can do the job and that there is plenty of support available.

Answer (score 0):

Before choosing a language, check if it has a good community and documentation associated with it. That can go a long way in helping you when you get stuck. Apart from that, every language has its pros and cons. Look for scalability because, at some point of time, you will have to consider that. And, definitely, go for a powerful platform. Do not just choose a programming language, choose a programming platform with a good framework.